# MSSQL Reporting Services report subscription won't forward to email outside of domain

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, ssrs

MSSQL Reporting Services 2000 on Windows Server 2003
MS Exchange 2007 on Windows Server 2007

I have a report subscription that I need to deliver to a user with an email address outside the domain.

I have set up the following for both the user and myself:
An exchange mailbox
A contact forward
A Mail Flow setup on the exchange mailbox that forwards to the contact

The report is addressed to the user's exchange address as well as my exchange address.  When it executes, I receive the report on my external (forwarded) address, but the user does not.  I can see the user's exchange address in the cc field of the message.

The user swears that the report is not in his junk mail folder.

If I forward the report (or any other email) from my external address to the user's exchange address, he receives it correctly at his external (forwarded) address.

How do I troubleshoot this beyond what I have done?

EDIT:
We are getting a 550 Administrative Prohibition status back from the user's email host.  I checked our server's ip on http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx and everything comes up clean.  Note that some messages are forwarded to this user successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the Non-Delivery Report (NDR) for your outgoing email, then follow the troubleshooting steps on [this Technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124840%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx).

The simplest path would be to try sending the report file to the external address from an *internal* mailbox which you *DO* have access to.  This should result in an NDR email being sent to the internal mailbox, which will tell you what is going wrong.

Once you have an idea why the delivery is failing from an Exchange mailbox, you'll want to verify that failure code is actually the same when the Reporting Server sends the email.  Assuming that your Reporting Server is sending the email out via SMTP directly, you will have to find the NDR in a log somewhere else, since there may be no mailbox to send the NDR to.  This page has good information on [How to Monitor Exchange NDRs](http://www.petri.co.il/monitor-exchange-2007-non-delivery-reports-ndr.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Is Exchange set up to allow relaying from your SQL server? If not, then no email to outside domains will be forwarded through the system from SMTP sources.

Check out the following link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2006/12/28/3397620.aspx

Comment: That sounds to be the likely reason.

Comment: I'm not sure how Exchange is configured, but the message is successfully relayed to my external email address, so I am thinking that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any Exchange 2007 Contact Message Delivery Restrictions on your coworker's contact.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397214(EXCHG.80).aspx